# MySQL performance issue comparing 2 DateTime fields on the same table

Tags: mysql

My `feed_listingjob` has 2 datetime fields:

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| data       | longtext    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| meta_data  | longtext    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| state      | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| error      | longtext    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| job_id     | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime(6) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime(6) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| es_sync_at | datetime(6) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`updated_at` and `es_sync_at` both are indexed individually as below:

```
mysql> show indexes from feed_listingjob;
+-----------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table           | Non_unique | Key_name                                                     | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| feed_listingjob |          0 | PRIMARY                                                      |            1 | id          | A         |       64534 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| feed_listingjob |          1 | feed_listingjob_job_id_4c3b1b514481f269_fk_feed_importjob_id |            1 | job_id      | A         |        2081 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| feed_listingjob |          1 | feed_listingjob_fde81f11                                     |            1 | created_at  | A         |       64534 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| feed_listingjob |          1 | feed_listingjob_afd1a1a8                                     |            1 | updated_at  | A         |       64534 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| feed_listingjob |          1 | feed_listingjob_381895a2                                     |            1 | es_sync_at  | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And my query is not using the indexes:

```
mysql> explain SELECT `feed_listingjob`.`id` FROM `feed_listingjob` WHERE `feed_listingjob`.`es_sync_at` < `feed_listingjob`.`updated_at` LIMIT 10;
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | feed_listingjob | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 53534 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Can someone please tell me why and how to optimise this query?

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless. The order in which you want rows returned may impact on the choice of index.

Comment: so one way to have it use indexes is to have an order by. Also joins

Answer (score 2):

The index can't be used here because `feed_listingjob`.`updated_at` is not a constant. Which means every row would have to be examined to check the condition. One way to use the index would be to have another column which stores the difference between es_sync_at and updated_at timestamps. If you store it as difference = (es_sync_at - updated_at timestamps) then the query becomes (difference < 0).

Comment: That's what I thought as well, looks like field comparisons should be avoided on big tables.

Comment: Field comparison is ok as long as it is being compared to a constant and no evaluation is needed on the field itself. For eg. comparing an int column to a string such as '123' will be much slower than comparing it to 123 as comparing it '123' means the int field needs to be converted to a string.

Comment: What do you mean by constant, I thought you mean `field < 123` which `123` is constant because it doesn't change throughout the whole query, but your comments above seems it means something else.

Comment: I meant '123' as a string vs 123 as an integer. Both are still constants but one involves conversion.